# This is an expression for the computation of kurtosis.

Tags: wavelet, statistics, random-process

[image]

However, I don't understand what the subscript '4x' or the parameter (0,0) stand for. Could anyone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a stationary process $x$, moments and cumulants, when they exist, depend on relative time lags, hence $n-1$ variables when the moment or cumulant is of order $n$ (see for instance [Basic Signal Processing and Statistics](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/663/bbm%253A978-1-4471-4546-2%252F1.pdf), p. 446 sq.):

$ \mathcal{M} \{ x(k),x(k+\tau_1),x(k+\tau_2),x(k+\tau_3) \} = \mathrm{E} \{ x(k)x(k+\tau_1)x(k+\tau_2)x(k+\tau_3) \}\,. $

A standard notation is $m_{4x}(\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3)$, where $x$ denotes the  process, $4$ the $n$-th order, $\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3$ the lags, with a triple $0$ for the $0$-lag cumulants. The first $0$-lag cumulants are classicaly named variance, skewness and kurtosis. Your version seems a normalized kurtosis, which could be written, with the above notations:
$$ \kappa_{4x}(0,0,0) = \frac{m_{4x}(0,0,0)}{m_{2x}^2(0)}\,. $$ 
I am quite surprised thant you only have two zeroes in your parenthesis.

On the  origin side, [kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) comes for a greek word meaning arched, curved, measuring the tailedness of a distribution.

Comment: I'm computing the kurtosis for a wavelet sub band matrix. I'm directly using the fourth central moment and the standard deviation for this purpose. I'm supposed to modify my sub band matrix using a threshold on kurtosis.

Comment: Strange: the normalized kurtosis is scale-invariant, while thresholds not in general.

Comment: Documentation on the thresholding process is really scant and it's kind of part of a bigger process. As a newbie, this is turning out to be hard.

Comment: There are quantities of papers related to wavelet thresholding, I hope you  will find hints in them. Was your initial kurtosis question answered properly?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to. The initial question's been answered. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Manish Ramesh Then, do not hesitate to mark the question as answered!